# multiple background image placement

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to place a background image at the top and bottom of a page. The top image works fine.  However, the bottom image only goes to the bottom of the screen but I would like it to go to the bottom of the entire page which is extends beyond the screen. Here is the code I'm using:

```
body { 
background-image: url('../images/image1.jpg'), url('../images/image2.jpg'); 
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x; 
background-position:left top, left bottom; 
}
```

How can I get image2 to the bottom of the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Place an absolutely positioned `div` inside your `body` tag and use that to contain the bottom image.

```
    <body>
       <div id="bottom-pic">
          Image here
       </div>
    </body>

   body { 
      position: relative;
      background-image:url('../images/image-top.jpg'); 
      background-repeat: repeat-x; 
      background-position:top left;
    }
    #bottom-pic{
      width:100%;
      height:200px;
      background-image: url('../images/image-bottom.jpg'); 
      background-repeat: repeat-x; 
      background-position:bottom left;
      position: absolute;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
    }
```